# Basemap not appearing: upgrade from OpenLayers 3.0 to OpenLayers 3.3

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, basemap

I recently updated my work's app to OL 3.3 from OL 3.0. I had a few basemap layers that looked like this:

```
    "basemap1": new ol.layer.Tile({
                extent: new ol.proj.transformExtent([-180.0,-90.0,180.0,90.0], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
                source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                        tileUrlFunction: function(coordinate) {
                        if(coordinate == null){
                                return "";
                        }
                        var z = coordinate[0];
                        var x = coordinate[1];
                        var y = (1 << z) - coordinate[2] - 1;
                        return 'http://tileurl.com/'+z+'/'+x+'/'+y+'.png';
                        }
                }),
                visible: true
    })
```

Which worked just fine in OpenLayers 3.0, but for some reason aren't appearing in OL 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem ended up being the extent:

```
    extent: new ol.proj.transformExtent([-180.0,-90.0,180.0,90.0], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
```

Once this line was commented out, the basemap appeared as normal.